# Using antlr-3.4-complete.jar in Eclipse is slow

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr

I dived into Antlr a while ago, but I've noticed that the compile times are unbelievably long (the progress will sit at 100% for 5 minutes while Eclipse complains about Antlr).  When all Antlr references are removed, but antlr-3.4-complete.jar is still included, the problem persists.  As soon as it is removed from the build path, the compile time goes back down to infinitesimal.

Also, compiling more than once in a Eclipse session causes an out of memory error.

What could be going on?  Is it really recompiling the whole ANTLR library every time? How can I compile it in a timely manner?

**Edit**: The complaints eclipse gives are warning about inner classes (as shown below).

> [2012-08-13 22:23:39 - HoloCalc] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
>   attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (antlr.TokenStreamRewriteEngine$1) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Comment: Increase the eclipse heap space if it comes to out of memory errors.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that.  Increasing the heap space doesn't speed up the process at all, though.

Comment: You're question doesn't give sufficient information to provide better help. Did you check all eclipse log files? Could you give more details about *complains about antlr*?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've edited the original post with the console warning, is there anything else I can check?  There are no Antlr-related warnings produced by the project in the "Problems" tab.

Comment: Are you using the ANTLR IDE Eclipse plug-in?